# About my way to truncate tables in my test DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my **Rails** app development, When I run my **Rspec test**, I need to **truncate all tables in my test database** in `after(:all)` .

(That's to clean up all data in every table in test db)

To approach this, I am thinking to first get all `ActiveRecord` **models** which represent the **tables in test db**, then for each **model**, I use `delete_all` method to clean up each table. Thant's something like:

```
ALL_ACTIVE_RECORD_MODELS.each do |model|
      model.delete_all
end
```

I have **two questions** to ask regards to this:

**1.** How to get **all active record models** in Rails in my rspec code?

**2.** Am I using a acceptable way to truncate all tables in my test DB or not? If not, what is the alternative way?

Comment: As so often when it comes to stuff you might want to do with rails, there's a gem for that: https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a gem to do exactly this task called database_cleaner: https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.

It will make sure that everything is removed from your database however its default strategy is not to delete content but to use transactions and simply roll back the changes after each test.

Be warned that this can occasionally lead to a gotcha when testing behaviour that's intended to be transactional as you won't see your transaction execute. You can fix this by adding `self.use_transactional_fixtures = false` before any set of tests that you don't want to use transactions. Remember to clear your data away again afterward though.

Comment: How about my first question? Though it is not needed if I use database cleanner gem...But I am still interested to know.

Comment: You could read your database schema and infer it - other than that I'm afraid I don't know